# AKS pod doesnt work with Azure files storage class

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

My pgadmin deployment doesnt work with azurefiles storageclass.
When deploying with azure files, the pod is unresponsive and after some time the pod logs give the following output:

```
2022-10-28 08:58:46,535: ERROR  pgadmin:        Exception in database migration.
```

When I deploy with azure disk storage class, it seems to work.
I have tried with the AKS built-in storage classes, but I also created a custom class with dir_mode and file_mode set:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: azurefile-default
provisioner: file.csi.azure.com # replace with "kubernetes.io/azure-file" if aks version is less than 1.21
allowVolumeExpansion: true
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=0
  - gid=0
  - mfsymlinks
  - cache=strict
  - actimeo=30
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
```

The storage account and file share get created but there is no real content (only 0kb size files)
[image]

Comment: Is the correct csi installed? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-csi

Comment: yes, aks has those classes built in. I used the azurefile-csi class